# searching by query string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I have a form in my asp.net mvc view as follow:

```
 <%using (Html.BeginForm("SearchBorrowed", "Admin", FormMethod.Get))
          { %>
        <%: Html.TextBox("searchTerm", Request.QueryString["searchterm"])%>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        <br />
        Is Returned :
        <%:Html.CheckBox("IsReturned")%>
        <%} %>
```

and here is the  'SearchBorrowed' action:

```
public ActionResult SearchBorrowed(bool IsReturned=false, string searchTerm = null)
        {
            IEnumerable<BorrwoinfInfo> bs;

            //...Get from repository

            return View(bs.ToList());

        }
```

and finally routing settings :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            "SearchBorrowed", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{*searchTerm}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Admin",
                action = "SearchBorrowed",

                searchTerm = UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
```

when I submit the form without checking 'IsReturned' Checkbox,
it returns result and the url gets as follow :

.../SearchBorrowed?searchterm=&IsReturned=false

But when I check IsReturned' Checkbox, the urls gets like this:

.../SearchBorrowed?searchterm=s&IsReturned=true&IsReturned=false

Why there is two IsReturned in above url ?!

How Could I fix this ?

Comment: I would recommend using a strongly typed model.

Comment: This is a search form inside a view which gets it model as 
'IEnumerable<BorrwoinfInfo>' so I cant bind checkbox to model.
If I want to do that, I have to use ViewModel, Am I Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why there is two IsReturned in above url ?!

Because the `Html.CheckBox` helper generates an additional hidden input field with the same name as the checkbox. If you look at the generated HTML you will see that the helper generated the following 2 input fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsReturned" id="IsReturned" value="true" checked="checked" />
<input type="hidden" name="IsReturned" id="IsReturned" value="false" />
```

This is by design. This helper is intended to be bound to a boolean property on your view model. When a checkbox field is not checked no value is sent to the server, so if there was not no hidden field you wouldn't be able to bind it to a boolean field.

If you don't want this hidden field you could either write a custom helper or generate the checkbox field manually.

Comment: I replaced that with '<input type="checkbox" name="IsReturned"/>'
but during debugging, I check 'IsReturned'paramater in 'SearchBorrowed' Action, and I see the value has not been affected by checkbox value. Wy ?

Comment: @persianDev, that's because you didn't specify a value for your checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" name="IsReturned" value="true" />`. Notice the `value="true"` attribute.